# LIKE clause on text field with "|" returns no results

Tags: sql, pattern-matching, amazon-redshift

I run into a very strange problem when I have a string with `|` separator in my `WHERE` clause.

For example the following code return adequate values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM stats
  WHERE name like 'Display |%'
ORDER BY 1 ASC

Display | New         
Display | Rerunning
```

But when I do this (note the space after `|`, and with the characters after the space it's the same effect), I get *no results* for some reason.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM stats
      WHERE name like 'Display | %'
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Maybe I should escape "|" ? or why LIKE clause doesn't work?

Comment: The issue is likely the space. Are you confident the whitespace after the pipe is the same as your `LIKE` clause?

Comment: try check  WHERE name like '%|%'

Comment: The other space may be a TAB. See if this yields you the expected results: `WHERE name like 'Display |'||chr(9)||'%'`

Comment: check if `select ascii(substr(name,10));` is 32, and also `select ascii(substr('Display | %',10));`

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Redshift? Please only add a tag  for the DBMS for the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 1):

You could use an equivalent [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) instead to cover all kinds of white space:

```
...
WHERE name ~ '^Display\s+\|\s*'
...
```

`\s+` .. 1 or more white space characters ([class-shorthand](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) for `[[:space:]]`)

`\s*` .. 0 or more of the same

The `|` has to be escaped to `\|` since it has a special meaning in regular expressions (but *not* in `LIKE` patterns).

Above links are to the Postgres manual. [The manual page for Redshift.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html)